# Renaming files from tuple

Tags: python-3.x

I have a batch of word files that I rename based on a tuple I created. The files have a unique value in the name I check against my tuple.
After revisiting this a day later, I figured out my for loop, and now my code renames all of my files in the dir I specify.  I modified my code to show my changes.

Also I am new to Python, so if there is anything else, I can change to make my code more efficient please share or if my description terminology is not stated correctly.

```
import os
eft = ['EFT0002078','EFT0002079','EFT0002080','EFT0002081']
file_name = ['200061564_202010_1ST ALLERGY ASTHMA',
             '200088994_202010_3G MEDICAL',
             '200060694_202010_ACADEMY PARK',
             '200073620_202010_ARVADA PEDIATRIC']
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\jack\\Python3.8')
tuplex = list(zip(eft, file_name))
src = os.listdir()
i=0
for src, ele in zip(src,tuplex):
    if ele[0] in src:
        dst = ele[1]
        os.rename(src,dst + '.docx')
i+=1
```

Before and after file name for my 1st file.

**src name:** Health Alliance_EFT0002078
**dst name:** 200061564_202010_1ST ALLERGY ASTHMA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zip()` allows for "merging" lists that have equal number of elements, otherwise you pair up only those few, that occur in the shorter one. To rename those files you need to prepare separate list, that contains actual matches. Try this one:

```
import os
eft = ['EFT0002078','EFT0002079','EFT0002080','EFT0002081']
file_name = ['200061564_202010_1ST ALLERGY ASTHMA',
         '200088994_202010_3G MEDICAL',
         '200060694_202010_ACADEMY PARK',
         '200073620_202010_ARVADA PEDIATRIC']
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\jack\\Python3.8')
tuplex = list(zip(eft, file_name))
src = os.listdir()

src_list = []
for ele in eft:
    for sr in src:
        if sr.find(ele) >=0:
            src_list.append(sr)

for old, new in zip(src_list, tuplex):
    os.rename(old, new[1] + '.docx')
```